# Make Safari 8 toolbar custom color using HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I´ve been trying to make a fixed div that makes Safari 8 toolbar the color I want, so it can fuse with my website seamlessly. Actually I´ve managed to make this work, but just half way.

The HTML markup I'm using is this:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="hiddenbar"></div>

<p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet bresaola </p>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html{
height:100%;
width: 100%;    
}

p{  
width:500px;
margin:0px auto;
text-align: center;
font-family: Helvetica, arial;
}

#hiddenbar{
position:fixed;
background-color: red;
height: 50px;
width:100%;
margin:-57px auto;
}
```

This works barely fine, as I need to scroll a little to make the toolbar change it color, and It leaves a tiny portion of color down the bar, but a proper `z-index` should fix the last one.

Here´s a demonstration of the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apRxjiaKqzs

Any hint on how to make it work without the need to scroll?

Comment: Maybe you could use JavaScript to do the scrolling automatically when the page loads.

Comment: Yeah, but the user could scroll to the top and the toolbar will go gray again.